# Save embedded resource to the file system

Tags: c++, winapi

I use this code to load embedded resource (bitmap image)

```
HRSRC hResInfo = ::FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceId), RT_BITMAP);
HGLOBAL hRes = ::LoadResource(hInstance, hResInfo);
LPVOID memRes = ::LockResource(hRes);
DWORD sizeRes = ::SizeofResource(hInstance, hResInfo);
```

It works fine.

How I can to save it to the file **C:\image.bmp**?

This code creates only empty file:

```
HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(L"C:\\image.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
::WriteFile(hFile, memRes, sizeRes, &dwWritten, NULL);
::CloseHandle(hFile);
```

**SOLUTION:**
Create new type "BMP" in resources and place image
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceId), **_T("BMP")**);

Comment: You could use the CImage class or GDI+ to get a bitmap encoder.  The more practical problem is that programs can't write files to the C: root folder without UAC elevation.  This is really the kind of job for an installer.

Comment: My program runs with elevated privileges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateFile()`, `WriteFile()`, and `CloseHandle()`.

`WriteFile()` takes a pointer and a size so can write from the locked resource directly.