# How to instruct MSVC to embed symbols in the executable?

Tags: visual-c++, debug-symbols

When I compile my program with MinGW, symbols get embedded in the executable:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("Hello, world!");
}

$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
$ nm hello.exe | grep main
0000000000402b50 T __getmainargs
000000000040829c I __imp___getmainargs
00000000004015e0 T __main
0000000000402c90 T main
00000000004014e0 T mainCRTStartup
0000000000407010 b mainret
0000000000407968 B __mingw_winmain_hInstance
0000000000407960 B __mingw_winmain_lpCmdLine
0000000000403000 D __mingw_winmain_nShowCmd
0000000000403024 D __native_dllmain_reason
0000000000401180 t __tmainCRTStartup
```

I would like to replicate this with the MSVC compiler:

```
$ cl hello.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29112.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
$ nm hello.exe
nm: hello.exe: no symbols
```

With the `/debug` or `/Zi` flag, the result is similar - a pdb file is created, but no symbols in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding debug symbols within the output binary is not supported by Visual C++. It's a feature that GCC+GDB supports, but not Visual C++.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160

> It is not possible to create an .exe or .dll that contains debug information. Debug information is always placed in a .obj or .pdb file.

---

As an alternative approach, you could embed the output PDB file as a Win32 Resource and [extract that file on launch via a command-line switch for when you want to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384610/save-embedded-resource-to-the-file-system). You'll need some custom *post*-build steps to do this as the `rc` step happens before the final EXE is generated.